# determine if it is jenkins environment inside gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, build.gradle

I am just wondering is it possible that I can tell whether I am in a Jenkins environment inside gradle? I just want to do something like

```
if (jenkins){
  //do something
}else{
  //do other
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check for existence of build-specific environment variables, like `$BUILD_ID` or `$BUILD_URL`, etc. They really *shouldn't* exist outside of Jenkins build, but if your environment is polluted, you could have them.

Comment: Thanks, just found that I can actually add an environment variable in jenkins and I can just check that.